# Java - hack or modify public variable in object via application

Tags: java, spring, oop, public

I am developing application via Spring.

I would like to ask is there any possibility that someone able to change the value of public variable in Object via any injection or hacking?

I have a Object class similar to this:

```
public class ObjectA {
    public String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

Comment: key is not a public variable here.

Comment: Sorry Prashant, I have edit it to "public String key;". How about this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by "any injection or hacking"?

Answer (score 1):

An attacker with no access to the system can exploit a bug, weak passwords, misconfiguration or an unprotected port to gain access to the system.

An attacker with access to the system can use privilege escalation methods to manipulate system into giving him/her additional permissions.

An attacker with sufficient privileges on the system can always access and manipulate memory contents, regardless if the variables are declared private or public.

An attacker with physical access to the system can always open the computer and attach probes to signals on the motherboard to bypass any access controls implemented in software.

The only "safe" data is either (a) at rest and encrypted with strong encryption, or (b) stored in hardware security modules (HSM) which are physically sealed and designed in such a way that the data is never sent outside of sealed chip.

Answer (score 0):

Why would they need to do that in the first place? There is a setter method.

Comment: Hi Matt Crysler, I am just wondering how the public variable in this scenario exposed the weakness for attacker to attack. Can I know what is the sweeter method you mention?

Comment: In general, if you have a getter and setter then your variable should be private. This is essentially one of the basic principles of object oriented design called encapsulation. Here is a useful article on encapsulation: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/encapsulation-in-java/amp/